# Campaign Record Lock After Status Update

Tags: locking

I want to "Lock" Campaign records for standard users once the Status field is changed to Completed, by the record owner. After it has been changed, the standard user should not be able to edit the record.  Only designated power users and sys admins should. I tried this with a validation rule but when the record owner tries changing the status to completed, he cannot save the record because of the validation rule.  Here is what I have so far:

```
$Permission.By_Pass_Validation_Rule=False&&
AND(
NOT(ISNEW()),
ISPICKVAL(Status, "Completed")
```

)

Not sure what I am missing above? Perhaps there is a better approach? Please note, apex or managed packages are not options in our environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this variant of your rule instead:

```
AND(
    NOT($Permission.By_Pass_Validation_Rule),
    NOT(ISNEW()),
    ISPICKVAL(Status, "Completed")
)
```